# Is align instruction necessary in LLVM IR code?

Tags: clang, llvm, jit, llvm-ir

When using clang++ to generate IR code, it will contain `align x` instruction, and the memory of variables and struct is aligned. Such as:

```cpp
struct CT {
  char   c1;
  bool   b1;
  int    i1;
  double d1; // 8
  char   c2;
  int    i2;
};

int main() {
  char c1 = 'a';
  int  i1 = 2;
  char c2 = 'b';
  char c3 = 'c';
  int  i2 = 4;
  printf("address of c1 = %p ;\n", &c1);
  printf("address of i1 = %p ;\n", &i1);
  printf("address of c2 = %p ;\n", &c2);
  printf("address of c3 = %p ;\n", &c3);
  printf("address of i2 = %p ;\n", &i2);

  return 0;
}
```

It will generate IR code (with align instructions):

```cpp
source_filename = "oper.cpp"
target datalayout = "e-m:o-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-apple-macosx10.15.0"

@.str = private unnamed_addr constant [22 x i8] c"address of c1 = %p ;\0A\00", align 1
@.str.1 = private unnamed_addr constant [22 x i8] c"address of i1 = %p ;\0A\00", align 1
@.str.2 = private unnamed_addr constant [22 x i8] c"address of c2 = %p ;\0A\00", align 1
@.str.3 = private unnamed_addr constant [22 x i8] c"address of c3 = %p ;\0A\00", align 1
@.str.4 = private unnamed_addr constant [22 x i8] c"address of i2 = %p ;\0A\00", align 1

; Function Attrs: noinline norecurse optnone ssp uwtable
define i32 @main() #0 {
  %1 = alloca i32, align 4
  %2 = alloca i8, align 1
  %3 = alloca i32, align 4
  %4 = alloca i8, align 1
  %5 = alloca i8, align 1
  %6 = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 0, i32* %1, align 4
  store i8 97, i8* %2, align 1
  store i32 2, i32* %3, align 4
  store i8 98, i8* %4, align 1
  store i8 99, i8* %5, align 1
  store i32 4, i32* %6, align 4

  %7 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([22 x i8], [22 x i8]* @.str, i64 0, i64 0), i8* %2)
  %8 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([22 x i8], [22 x i8]* @.str.1, i64 0, i64 0), i32* %3)
  %9 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([22 x i8], [22 x i8]* @.str.2, i64 0, i64 0), i8* %4)
  %10 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([22 x i8], [22 x i8]* @.str.3, i64 0, i64 0), i8* %5)
  %11 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([22 x i8], [22 x i8]* @.str.4, i64 0, i64 0), i32* %6)
  ret i32 0
}

declare i32 @printf(i8*, ...) #1
```

This will output:

```cpp
address of c1 = 0x7ffee900328b ;
address of i1 = 0x7ffee9003284 ;
address of c2 = 0x7ffee9003283 ;
address of c3 = 0x7ffee9003282 ;
address of i2 = 0x7ffee900327c ;
```

We can see that the memory of variables is aligned.

But if you delete the align instruction of IR code, it will run correctly too, and the memory of variables is also aligned. Such as below IR code:

```cpp
source_filename = "oper.cpp"
target datalayout = "e-m:o-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-apple-macosx10.15.0"

@.str = private unnamed_addr constant [22 x i8] c"address of c1 = %p ;\0A\00"
@.str.1 = private unnamed_addr constant [22 x i8] c"address of i1 = %p ;\0A\00"
@.str.2 = private unnamed_addr constant [22 x i8] c"address of c2 = %p ;\0A\00"
@.str.3 = private unnamed_addr constant [22 x i8] c"address of c3 = %p ;\0A\00"
@.str.4 = private unnamed_addr constant [22 x i8] c"address of i2 = %p ;\0A\00"

; Function Attrs: noinline norecurse optnone ssp uwtable
define i32 @main() #0 {
  %1 = alloca i32
  %2 = alloca i8
  %3 = alloca i32
  %4 = alloca i8
  %5 = alloca i8
  %6 = alloca i32
  store i32 0, i32* %1
  store i8 97, i8* %2
  store i32 2, i32* %3
  store i8 98, i8* %4
  store i8 99, i8* %5
  store i32 4, i32* %6
  %7 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([22 x i8], [22 x i8]* @.str, i64 0, i64 0), i8* %2)
  %8 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([22 x i8], [22 x i8]* @.str.1, i64 0, i64 0), i32* %3)
  %9 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([22 x i8], [22 x i8]* @.str.2, i64 0, i64 0), i8* %4)
  %10 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([22 x i8], [22 x i8]* @.str.3, i64 0, i64 0), i8* %5)
  %11 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([22 x i8], [22 x i8]* @.str.4, i64 0, i64 0), i32* %6)
  ret i32 0
}

declare i32 @printf(i8*, ...) #1
```

This will also output the aligned address of variables, no matter you use clang command or LLJIT(Tool's API of LLVM).

---

My Question:

1. We could not add align instruction to IR code? LLVM JIT will add it automatically?

Comment: LLVM has configurable alignment per data' type, as specified in the target layout. However, you can also specify alignment in an alloca instruction, which is useful sometimes, because not every rule of every source language maps cleanly to the target layout system. Sometimes compilers generate redundant output, and the same effect is specified in two ways. This seems like one of those times.

Comment: Got it, thanks for reply.